# Declaring UI Objects in Switch Cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, scope, switch-statement, declaration

I've read about the scope of switch cases, being *jump labels* and all, but the suggested solutions here at SO seem to imply that adding curly braces would circumvent the issue. However, this still doesn't seem to work:

```
switch (objectType) {

  case label:   //label is an integer constant
    NSLog(@"statement before declaration");
    UILabel *control = [[UILabel alloc] init];       //no error
    break;

  case button:  //button is an integer constant
    {
      UIButton *control = [[UIButton alloc] init];   //no error
    }
    break;    

  default:
    break;
}

// error when trying to use the *control* variable,
// Use of undeclared identifier 'control'
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with switch statements?

---

23rd May 2015: *been trying many different approaches to no success.*

**EDIT: Errors when implementing Cyrille's suggested solution:**

```
UIView *control = nil;
switch (objectType)
{
  case label:  //button is an integer constant
    {
      control = [[UILabel alloc] init];   //no error

      //error: property 'text' not found on object of type 'UIView *'
      control.text = @"Something...";     
    }
    break; 

  default:
    break;
}
```

Apparently, even after being recast from *UIView* to *UILabel*, the object did not inherit all the properties of *UILabel*, and thus the error:

**Property 'text' not found on object of type 'UIView *'**

Even Zil's suggestion to prefix the type `(UILabel*)[[UILabel alloc]init];` did not work.

Did anyone get this to work?

---

**SOLUTION by DUNCAN C.** *(see accepted answer below)*

```
    UIView *control = nil;
    switch (objectType)
    {
        case label:  
            control = [[UILabel alloc] init];
            ((UILabel *)control).text = @"Something...";     
            break; 

        default:
            break;
    }

    // UI object instantiated inside switch case recognised!
    ((UILabel *)control).textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

*Thank you Duncan C.*

Comment: Note that your code outside the switch statement will crash at runtime if you have another case, button, that creates a button and assigns `control=button`. That's because in that case, the control object doesn't contain a label, it contains a button and if you cast it to UILabel, you're telling the compiler "trust me, it's a label" but you're wrong.

Comment: @Duncan C: You're absolutely correct; I noticed that too before posting, but just wanted to indicate simply that the object is indeed recognised outside of the switch block. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for scope in Objective-C are pretty simple. Any time you enter a pair of curly braces, you enter a new level of scope. Any variable declared inside that scope only exists inside that scope. When you exit the braces, the variable ceases to exist.

The individual cases inside a switch don't need braces, so they don't define a local level of scope, but the entire switch statement **does** use braces, and so it does define a local scope. Any variable declared inside the switch statement's braces doesn't exist outside the braces.

When you enter a new level of scope you have access to everything declared in your parent scope.

You don't make it completely clear what it is you want to do. I `THINK` what you want to do is have a variable of a parent class, and then put new objects in it that are from subclasses, and still have access to the unique properties of the child class.

If you declare a variable of a base class, you can assign any object that is a subclass of that type to the variable.

If you want access to the properties of the subclass, through, you have to cast the variable to the appropriate type:

```
UIView *control = nil;
switch (objectType)
{
  case label:  
    control = [[UILabel alloc] init];   //no error

    ((UILabel *)control).text = @"Something...";     
    break; 
  case button: 
    control = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [((UIButton *)control) setTitle: "Foo" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
  default:
    break;
}
```

### EDIT

I find the casting syntax to be a pain to type, and it can get confusing. Sometimes it's clearer to create a new temporary variable of the object's actual type, do whatever you need to do, and then assign it to the target variable, like this:

```
UIView *control = nil;
switch (objectType)
{
  case label:  
    UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];   //no error

    aLabel.text = @"Something...";   
    aLabel.someOtherProperty = someOtherValue;
    control = aLabel;  
    break; 
  case button: 
    UIButton aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [aButton setTitle: "Foo" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    control = aButton
  default:
    break;
}
```

Outside the switch statement, you won't know which type of object the control variable contains, so you will only be able to access the properties of the UIView base class, **unless** you cast the variable to the specific type, as shown above.

(Note that the name "control" above is a bad choice, since a label is not a control. Better to use a name like "aView" that implies the common class of all objects that might be in the variable.)

Comment: Wow! It works! `((UILabel *)control).text` - I wouldn't have figured that out on my own. Thank you, sincerely. So gracious of you to have taken on my question on request. I've followed a lot of your work, and I personally feel that your explanations are very clear and concise, and easy to understand. You should definitely write a book on the subject. Thank you Duncan.

Comment: No worries. See my edits for another way of doing it.

Comment: That would be priceless, although when assigned in that way, the *control* object outside of the switch block does not seem to inherit the properties of the respective control - *no text, textColor, etc. for label, for example*. Also, if I may, when the separate scoping for the individual case blocks *(ie: the curly brackets)* are removed, Xcode throws an error if the first line is the initializer for an object - `UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];`. If some function is inserted in the first line, say `NSLog()`, then it's alright. Why is that?

Comment: I have discovered the problem with declaring a new variable as the first line of a case as well, and don't know what causes it. It's annoying.

Comment: Truly so. Instead of placing an `NSLog()` at the beginning of every case block, would there be any issues if each case were enclosed in their own curly brackets? And did you also confirm that simply assigning a previously declared *UIView* object *(declared outside the switch block)* to an object instantiated within the switch block will not inherit the object's properties? Thank you again.

Comment: Your question about inheriting properties doesn't really make sense because it is based on some wrong assumptions. It's more than I can explain in a comment. Why not ask a new question specifically about that and I'll try to answer it there?

Comment: That's a good idea, and I've done just that [*(new question about inheritance)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414765/understanding-object-inheritance). Whenever you feel inclined, I'd be more than happy to hear your delightful explanations. Hitherto, I'm much obliged for your insightful solution to this question on declarations in switch cases. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, just declare a generic `control` before your switch:

```
UIView *control = nil;
switch (objectType) {

  case label:   //label is an integer constant
    NSLog(@"statement before declaration");
    control = [[UILabel alloc] init];       //no error
    break;

  case button:  //button is an integer constant
    {
      control = [[UIButton alloc] init];   //no error
    }
    break; 

  case other:
    control = [[UIView alloc] init]; // works too   

  default:
    break;
}

NSLog(@"Control frame is %@", NSStringFromCGRect(control.frame));
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know that UI elements could be re-cast that way. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Nope, nope, I was wrong. A `UILabel` is not a `UIResponder`. Just use the standard `UIView` or `id` type (edited answer)

Comment: `NSObject > UIResponder > UIView > UILabel` vs `NSObject > UIResponder > UIView > UIControl > UIButton`, the common ancestor is `UIView`.

Comment: Unfortunately neither the *UIControl* nor the *UIView* declarations seem to be compatible. When recasting as *UILabel*, for example, the declaration works, but *property ... not found* errors pop up when trying to assign text, textAlignment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Once you declare your control as `UIView *`, if you try to access properties that doesn't exists on UIView you will get an error.

However as Duncan C saids you can always cast and access to the property using dot notation, example:

```
((UILabel *)control).text = @"This Works";
```

and then access the value

```
NSLog(@"Control text: %@", ((UILabel *)control).text);
```

I purpose a different approach, declare your control as `id` and use Objective-C method invocation. You need to make sure that the control responds to the selector that you're trying to invoke. If you want to protect your app for crash when you try to access a selector, you can use `respondsToSelector:` method.
An example of my suggestion:

```
unsigned objectType = 1;
id control = nil;

switch (objectType) {

    case 1:   //label is an integer constant
        NSLog(@"statement before declaration");
        control = [[UILabel alloc] init];       //no error
        [control setText:@"a"];
        break;

    case 2:  //button is an integer constant
    {
        control = [[UIButton alloc] init];   //no error
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

NSLog(@"Control text %@", [control text]);
```

And the result is:

```
2015-05-23 13:12:06.840 test2[46589:12231454] statement before declaration
2015-05-23 13:12:06.841 test2[46589:12231454] Control text `a`
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Using the `id` type seems to work, although it appears that dot notation would not work on such an object - only method messaging. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `control` variable is declared inside the scope of the switch statement and then you are trying to use it outside:

```
UILabel *controlLabel = nil;
UIButton *controlButton = nil;

    /*
    I've defined two variables but you could do the same with one like so
    id control = nil;
    or
    UIControl *control = nil;
    */

switch (objectType) {

  case label:   //label is an integer constant
    NSLog(@"statement before declaration");
    controlLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];       //no error
    break;

  case button:  //button is an integer constant
    {
      controlButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];   //no error
    }
    break;    

  default:
    break;
}

if (controlLabel) {

} else if (controlButton) {

}
```

Comment: That just kills the point in having a single `control` variable.

Comment: You can achieve the same with id or UIControl, it might be easier like this so that you don't have to typecast later.

Comment: @RASS: Yes, but recasting from *UIControl* or *UIView* seems to have some property compatibility issues.

Comment: even when doing `(UILabel*)[[UILabel alloc]init];`  ?

Comment: @Zil: Yes. Even with `(UILabel*)[[UILabel alloc]init];` Am I missing something?

Comment: Well we definitly are missing somethign but I can't quite see what.

Comment: Cyrille & RASS answers are correct and almost identical ; the only important thing is to only have one control instead of two (but the edit made from RASS changed that difference). So essentially both their answers should work because both their answers are correct.

Comment: @Zil: RASS' suggestion, to declare a different variable for each type works. But the `UIControl` or `UIView` declarations to a single variable didn't. The properties aren't the same, even after recasting.

Comment: @iSofia if you have a control variable of type `id` and you set it to either `UIView` or `UIButton` (or whatever) you can then later identify and typecast like so: `if ([control isKindOfClass:[UIView Class]]){[(UIView *)control doSomething];}`

Comment: Look at inheritance and typecasting, using one control variable is definitely a valid option.

Comment: @Zil: You almost had it with `(UILabel*)` - only thing was to apply it to the instantiated object and not the initializer. Thank you.