# How to declare properties with a for loop in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, for-loop, uiviewcontroller

I have about 80 CALayer properties I need to add to a UIViewController and I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to do this with a for loop as opposed to me copying and pasting 80 lines of code like this:

```
var colorButton1 = CALayer()
var colorButton2 = CALayer()
var colorButton1 = CALayer()
var colorButton2 = CALayer()
var colorButton1 = CALayer()
var colorButton2 = CALayer()
........(colorbuttons go to 60)
```

I know how to make the objects with a for loop in the viewDidLoad method, like this:

```
    let colorLayers = 60
    var colorLayer = CALayer()
    var buttonYPosition:CGFloat = 0.0

    for colorNum in 1...60 {

        buttonYPosition = buttonYPosition + 50
        colorLayer.contents = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("color\(colorNum).png"))!.CGImage
        colorLayer.frame = CGRectMake(device.x/2, buttonYPosition, worldScale * 380, worldScale * 180)
        colorLayer.zPosition = 6.0
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(colorLayer)
    }
```

but these are not properties.

So how can I put something like this in the top of my script so it creates 60 properties with 60 different indexed names, as opposed to 60 objects with the same name?

I'm not even sure this is possible, I'm just hoping to condense my code.

Comment: As mentioned, create an array. You won't have individual "names" per-se, but the indexes in the array basically serve as that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with many objects of the same type, rather than declaring all of them separately, you should make an array of that object type. In the case of `CALayer`, you can initialize an array of 60 objects using the `count:repeatedValue` initializer like so:

```
var layers = [CALayer](count: 60, repeatedValue: CALayer())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Access all layers
    for layer in layers {
        // Do something
    }

    // Access an individual layer
    layers[0].frame = CGRectZero     
}
```

Notice you access individual layers using subscript notation, which is cleaner than doing layer1, layer2, layer3, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of CALayers:

```
var colorLayers =  [CALayer]()
```

Comment: Would it be possible to declare objects within switch cases, and still have access to them outside of those cases? I have a standing issue [(SO Question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368589/declaring-ui-objects-in-switch-cases), and from reading your various answers, you seem like the right person to ask. Sorry for being so forward. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone interested in my above question *(declaring objects within switch cases)*, Duncan C. has kindly posted the solution. [*(linked here)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368589/solved-declaring-ui-objects-in-switch-cases).